# Proving integral with finite number of values greater than any small number is $0$

Tags: real-analysis, integration

I was given this question and think it is mostly wrong,there were also more mistakes than what I am going to write, but I would like to know how wrong it is.So would there be any validity to this approach, or is it completely incorrect?

Question Suppose that $f:[0,1]\rightarrow [0,1]$ satisfies the following properties:given any $\epsilon>0,f(x)<\epsilon$ except at finitely many points, prove $\int_{0}^{1}f=0$

My attempt:

Let $T=\{y_1,...,y_m\}$ be the set of points such that $f(x) \geq \epsilon$ let $P=\{x_0,...,x_n\}$ be a partition of $[0,1]$.

Let $A=\{k|[x_{k-1},x_k] \cap T\neq \emptyset\}$
Let $B=\{k|[x_{k-1},x_k]\cap T=\emptyset\}$

Then there are at most $2m$ intervals having endpoints with indices in $A$ containing points in $T$. Let $P*$ be a partition containing these intervals such that

$\Delta x_k\leq\frac{\epsilon}{4m}$

Then $U(f,P*)=\sum_{k \in A}\text{sup}\{f(x)|x \in [x_{k-1},x_k]\}\Delta x_k<\frac{\epsilon}{2}$

similarly $L(f,P*)=\sum_{k \in A}\text{inf}\{f(x)|x \in [x_{k-1},x_k]\}\Delta x_k<\frac{\epsilon}{2}$

Now consider a partition $Q$ of intervals with endpoints with indices in $B$.

Let $\Delta x_k<\frac{1}{2(n-2m)}$ Then since $f(x)<\epsilon$ for $f$ on intervals having endpoints with indices in $B$

$U(f,Q)<\frac{\epsilon}{2}$ and $L(f,Q)<\frac{\epsilon}{2}$

Then $L(f,Q)+L(f,P*)<\epsilon$ and $U(f,Q)+U(f,P*)<\epsilon$

My question is was this on the right track of a correct approach?Is there a different way to approach this? When I saw the question I felt a similarity between this question and the proof that thomae's function is integrable, but I do not think I studied/understood that proof well enough, to successfully come up for a proof for this. And I realized in that proof, that didn't come up with separate partitions for intervals having endpoints with indices in $A,B$ like I did.

Comment: What if $f\equiv -1?$

Comment: @zhw How could that be since $f$ maps into the interval $[0,1]$?

Comment: Oh, sorry, you're right, didn't read carefully.

Comment: If you use measure theory, the measure of the set where $f(x)\gt 0)=0$, so the integral $=0$.

Comment: @herbsteinberg my class never studied measure theory

Comment: You can use the following result: Let $f:[a, b] \to\mathbb {R} $ be a bounded function. Then $f$ is Riemann integrable on $[a, b] $ if and only if for any given pair of positive real numbers $\epsilon, \sigma$ there is a corresponding positive number $\delta$ such that for any partition $P$ of $[a, b] $ with norm $||P||<\delta$, the subintervals of $P$ over which the oscillation of $f$ exceeds or equals $\epsilon $ have a total combined length less than $\sigma$.

Comment: @ParamanandSingh So where is my answer incorrect?And how incorrect is it?

Comment: Here you have to deal with the subintervals which contain points where values of $f$ exceed $\epsilon $.

Comment: what if I change the length of the second partition to $\Delta x_k<\frac{1}{2n}$?

Comment: You need to modify your answer to deal with $U-L$. The approach and idea is correct, some formal details need to be fixed.

Comment: so changing the second partition would not help things?

Comment: Or better just deal with upper sum $U$ and show that it can be made arbitrarily small.

Comment: I though choosing the partitions to be $\Delta x_k< \frac{\epsilon}{4m}$ would deal with this? why does it not?

Comment: It works, why do you think $\epsilon/4m$ does not work?

Comment: so where am I going wrong the most? I was thinking it was choosing the intervals not containing points in $T$ to have length $\Delta x_k<\frac{1}{2(n-2m)}$

Answer (score 1):

For each $n$ define $s_n=(x,f(x)\ge \frac{1}{n})$.  Hypothesis $s_n$ is finite.  Therefore $S=\cup_ns_n$ consisting of all points where $f(x) \gt 0 $ is countable.  Countable sets have measure zero, so the measure of the set where $f(x)=0$ is one and the integral $=0$.

Without measure theory: Since $S$ is countable, order the list $(x_k)$ and for each $k$ bracket the point by an interval $(x_k-\frac{\epsilon}{2^k},x_k+\frac{\epsilon}{2^k})$  Union of covering intervals has length $\lt 2\epsilon$. Let $\epsilon \to 0$, so integral over non-zero points $=0$.

Comment: Is there any validity to my approach? Or is it just completely wrong?

Comment: I stopped at $\Delta x_k \lt \frac{1}{2(n-2m)}$.  What happens when $2m=n$?

Comment: I wasn't trying to scoff.  But that line was used to imply following lines.  So at that point it looks very wrong.  Possibly a typo?  Did you have a restriction so $n\ne 2m$?

Comment: Would have it been mostly correct if I would have kept all intervals at maximum length, $\frac{\epsilon}{4m}$? Also I do not get why we cannot make the upper sum less than $\epsilon$. Honestly I would not say that that was a typo, but more of a mistake.

Comment: Also I am sorry about my rudeness earlier.

Comment: Your approach to $A$ is correct.  As far as $B$ is concerned, you don't need to define an interval structure, since the integrand $\le \epsilon$ for all points.  Therefore the contribution to the integral $\le \epsilon$, since the total length of the integration domain $=1$.

Answer (score 1):

Your idea is correct and simple. Just deal with $U(P, f) $.

Let $k$ be the number of points where $f(x) \geq\epsilon$. And choose norm of partition less than $\epsilon/2k$. The upper sum on intervals which don't contain these points does not exceed $\epsilon$. And on the intervals which contain these points the upper sum does not exceed $2k(\epsilon /2k)=\epsilon$. Hence the upper sum $U(P, f) $ does not exceed $2\epsilon $.

I am not sure why you chose different $\Delta x_k$ for these different types of intervals. This probably makes your proof a bit difficult to comprehend (at least for me).

You can see that we don't need to deal with lower sum separately because it is already non negative and does not exceed any upper sum.

Comment: \I was thinking choosing the second $\Delta x_k$ was wrong because if there are less than $2m$ intervals containing points in $T$, then the upper sum for the second partition would exceed $\frac{\epsilon}{2}$, because if say $n-m$ intervals contain points not in $T$, then $\Sigma_{k \in B}M_k \Delta x_k <\frac{(n-m) \epsilon}{2(n-2m)}$ which would exceed $\frac{\epsilon}{2}$, is this correct?

Comment: @ScottFrazier The intervals which don't contain points of  $T$ have a combined length not more than $1$. And values of $f$ here are less than $\epsilon$ so this part does not exceed $\epsilon $. You can't make it less than $\epsilon /2 $ and probably that's what you were trying.

Comment: So it was incorrect to say the lower and upper sums are less than $\epsilon/2$?

Comment: @ScottFrazier: so in your formulation the upper sum can't exceed $\epsilon +\epsilon/2=3\epsilon /2$. You wanted a fine $\epsilon $ at the end. But that's not really needed. An $\epsilon$ is as good as $3\epsilon /2$ (or $2\epsilon $ of my answer).

Comment: @ScottFrazier: yes that part about upper and lower sum both less than $\epsilon /2$ is incorrect